# What am I doing wrong with the loop use in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to compare emails from tables and if they match I need to show some data from the third table and I'm trying to do that through a while loop which goes through the string of all emails and compares them and if its a match it should get the data from third table

Im pasting the query from pastebin here: https://pastebin.com/zyjcJngf

The part where I want to use the loop

```
select distinct Email,
CASE dbo.spValueToString((SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM tblEmailBlackList WHERE tblEmailBlackList.Email=LiveCampaign_SubscriberList_Email.Email AND tblEmailBlackList.PortalID>=-1))
WHEN 'Da' THEN

    WHILE @vsi > 1
    BEGIN
        SET @testEmail = (SELECT LEFT(@resultCpy, CHARINDEX(',', @resultCpy) - 1)) --dobi prvi mail
        SET @testEmail = (SELECT REPLACE(@testEmail, ' ', '')) --zbriše vse ' ' če obstajajo
        SET @resultCpy = (SELECT SUBSTRING(@resultCpy, LEN(@testEmail) + 2, LEN(@resultCpy))) --odstani prvi mail
        IF      
            @testEmail = Email
            BREAK
        ELSE
            SET @vsi = @vsi - 1
    END
    SET @vsi = (SELECT LEN(@result) - LEN(REPLACE(@result, ',', '')) + 1)
    SET @resultCpy = @result

    (SELECT DISTINCT PortalLocalization.PortalName
    FROM tblEmailBlackList
    LEFT JOIN tblLiveCampaignSettings ON tblLiveCampaignSettings.ModuleID = tblEmailBlackList.ModuleID
    LEFT JOIN PortalLocalization ON PortalLocalization.PortalID = tblEmailBlackList.PortalID AND PortalLocalization.CultureCode = 'sl-SI'
    WHERE Email = @testEmail
    AND tblEmailBlackList.PortalID >= 0
    UNION
    SELECT DISTINCT PortalLocalization.PortalName
    FROM tblEmailBlackList
    LEFT JOIN vw_TabModules ON vw_TabModules.ModuleID = tblEmailBlackList.ModuleID
    LEFT JOIN PortalLocalization ON PortalLocalization.PortalID = vw_TabModules.PortalID AND PortalLocalization.CultureCode = 'sl-SI'
    WHERE Email = @testEmail
    AND tblEmailBlackList.PortalID = -1)    
ELSE 'Ne' END
AS LocalBlockList
FROM LiveCampaign_SubscriberList_Email
```

The problem I have here is that I get an error when I add the loop in the code, but if I run the loop alone it works. I get the incorrect syntax near WHILE and The multi-part identifier "LiveCampaign_SubscriberList_Email.Email" could not be bound.

Comment: Thats a lot of very specific code in there - we have no idea what those UDF's do. But most of all _you have not explained your problem_

Comment: Why does the above need to be in a `WHILE` in the first place? Also code like `@testEmail = Email` is going to fail, `Email`  has no context in that statement.

Comment: You can't run a loop like that, as part of a select statement, that's not valid T-SQL syntax and it's impossible to mix procedural (loops, conditions, etc.) and query code (select, update, etc.) in a single statement.

Comment: @Larnu trying to set the `@testEmail` to the email string which is then used to check in the third table also i use while to go through the string of emails separated with , and then compare each one from the row

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but isn't this just a LEFT JOIN issue?  You need data from two tables, and then data from a third if there's a match.  LEFT JOIN the first two, and then LEFT JOIN in the third?

Comment: None of that looks like it needs a `WHILE` @hyper. Splitting a delimited list, comparing data, can all be achieved via set based methods; and should be.

Comment: [Here](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) is a great place to start.

Comment: so I should be able to solve that with just joins? @Larnu

Comment: Difficult to tell, as we can't see your data, or know what your expected results are. There are, however, 100's of answers on how to split a string in SQL Server using a set based method; such as XML splitters and DelimitedSplit8k. SQL Server 2016 also supports the functionality natively (`STRING_SPLIT`), provided you don't need to retain ordinal position.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot put a "WHILE" inside SELECT statement.

Try to treat your data before the SELECT, maybe inside a temp Table.

Comment: Ok i dont think i can do that before SELECT but I can try it with a temp table but now again when I try to compare i get an error: Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.